# How to install devDependencies recursively 1 level deep?

Tags: npm, pnpm

by default `npm i` would install all dependencies recursively all layers deep
but what if I need to install devDependencies recursively 1 layer deep)?

That is because I'm bundling node_modules (webpack+babel actually rebuilds every dependency and then bundles it)

so I need devDependencies of my dependencies to install somehow *(1 layer deep basically)*
`npm i --no-save` works but probably that's a little stupid to do it manually